# ed: set first line as the default current line

Tags: editors, large-files, ed

I am trying to use `ed` to edit the first line of a large file, but I have to wait for `ed` to read all lines.  Is there any way I could stop `ed` from reading the whole file and start editing immediately, with the current line being the first line?

Comment: `ed` or `ex` can't do this. Unix utils expect to write to a file, not go in and fiddle with bytes of the file, or the file allocation table definitions. `sed '1d' file > newFile` will be about as fast as you can get without writing your own C program. Also, `ed` and `ex` (at least the ones I have worked with) are limited to the size of the file they can work on, often times by space available in /tmp (or /var/tmp) or in `ex` for the internal setting of directory. (You know `ex` is the steam version of `vi|vim`? Do `:set all` to find the value for directory). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by shellter `ed` cannot do this. Most editing operations require that the file is rewritten, only replacements can be done in-place, in that case you could use `hexedit(1)`.

The least memory hungry way is to use `sed` operations, e.g. to replace *August* with *June* on the first line:

```
sed '1s/August/June/' FILE > NEWFILE
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the solution using `sed`. I particularly find the `-i` flag useful in order to avoid creating temp files. I was looking for an `ed` solution, but I will give `hexedit` a try. Thank you.

Comment: @sina, `-i` does create a temporary file, but `sed` handles it transparently in the background. See `info sed` and search for `-i`.

Comment: This is bad news. But it does make sense considering shelter's comment and your explanations.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @sina Note that `ed` too may use temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to stop `ed` from reading in an entire file or to automatically make the first line of the editing buffer the current line after opening a document with the editor.

The `ed` editor always places you on the last line affected by a command (or just after or before when the command is `d`), and reading in a file at startup is akin to using `e filename`, which discards the current editing buffer, opens the named file for editing, and sets the current line to the last line read from the file.

Would you want to make changes to a large document in a non-interactive way, then using `sed` or `awk` may provide better alternatives as these tools work on streams and do not by default read the full document into memory.

If you really want to do interactive editing of huge documents, you may want to try splitting the document up in chunks with `split`, edit the chunks you're interested in modifying (using `ed` or `vi` or any other editor), and then simply using `cat` to concatenate the chunks back together.

---

Hypothetical editing session for editing the first 5 lines of a huge file in `ed`:

```
$ ed
e ! head -n 5 hugefile
123
g/^/m0
w ! { cat - ; tail -n +6 hugefile ; } >hugefile.new
Q
```

That is, request to edit the output of `head -n 5 hugefile`.  The edit I perform here is simply to reverse the lines (`g/^/m0`, "move each line, in turn, to before the first line"). Then write out the modified editing buffer to a shell command that concatenates the buffer's contents with line 6 and onward from the original file.  The result is written to a new filename. `Q` then quits the editor.